# Shopify: Order Print App is not picking up variables

Tags: shopify, liquid

I am trying to display a Final Sale message on order receipts for products that are 60% off. This bit of code does display the message on the individual product page, but when I insert in the template I'm using in the Order Printer app, the message does not seem to display.

I've contacted various Shopify support people, but they have not been able to identify the problem. Here's the code I'm inserting:

```
<!--if item is 60% off, it displays message: -->
  {% if product.compare_at_price %}
     {% assign sixtyPercentOff = product.compare_at_price | minus: product.price | times: 100.0 | divided_by: product.compare_at_price | round %} 
         {% if sixtyPercentOff == 60 %}
             <p style="color: #B21F1F;">
               This item is final sale -- no returns or exchanges are accepted.
              </p>
         {% endif %}
   {% endif %}
```

Is it because Order Printer does not recognize variables such as "compare_at_price"?

Answer (score 0):

`product.compare_at_price` doesn't exist.

For `product` you have: [`compare_at_price_max`](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/objects/product#product-compare_at_price_max), [`compare_at_price_min`](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/objects/product#product-compare_at_price_min), [`compare_at_price_varies`](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/objects/product#product-compare_at_price_varies)

Do you mean to use something like: `{% if product.compare_at_price_min > 0 %}`

Or if you have variants you can use directly [`variant.compare_at_price`](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/objects/variant#variant-compare_at_price)

For first available variant of product: `{% if product.variants[0].compare_at_price > 0 %}`

Comment: Thanks @jrbedard . I tried this in the Template but still had no luck:

`{% for line_item in line_items %}
{% if line_item.product.compare_at_price_min > 0 %}
<p style="color: #B21F1F;">
This item is final sale -- no returns or exchanges are accepted.
 </p>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}`